# Swagger Local Editor change Service host/port

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I want to use the Swagger editor to test my REST service deployed with Grizzly.
My service is on a different port (8081) then the Swagger editor (8080).
How can I tell the editor (local or online) to use another port?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, haven't tested it yet:

Under the swagger object, there's a fixed field called host:

> The host (name or ip) serving the API. This MUST be the host only and
>   does not include the scheme nor sub-paths. It MAY include a port. If
>   the host is not included, the host serving the documentation is to be
>   used (including the port). The host does not support path templating.

taken from:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md